# What is the right way to upload images to server (or S3) in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have application built on `Ember.js (2.13)`. I have `User` model and at this moment I work on avatar upload feature. When I modify model and save it then Ember makes `PATCH` request to my API during it `Ember` serializer builds nice `json-api` object and I like it.

When I need to upload image to server I need to make some `PUT` request to my API with file data I could use `jQuery` ajax for this. Server will resize and crop image and save it on disk or push it to `S3` bucket. But I do not like this way because this request will be created bypassing Ember's serializer and without references to model. So I need to set uploaded filename to `User` model and save it then I'll have redundant request to server.

I have an idea to transform file to `base64` string in Ember.js app and set this string to `User` model and save it. In this case I'll have one request to server. Is this good way to upload file?

Please advice best practice of uploading files in `Ember.js` application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I do not like this way because this request will be created
>   bypassing Ember's serializer and without references to model.

There is nothing you can do about this - ember data does not support files. And in many situations ED is not good enough (for example - nested resource URIs, partial updates). I suggest to not be bothered about it too much - if your can't perform some request using ember data, just use `Ember.$.ajax`.

> So I need to set uploaded filename to User model and save it then I'll
>   have redundant request to server.

No, you don't. Just configure your backend to return full user model (as you do for other get/post/update requests which use ED), and pass result (if request was successful, of course) to [pushPayload](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload) method of the `store`. Store will be updated with actual data without additional requests. Example:

```
this.get('session').authorize('authorizer:token', (headerName, headerValue) => {
  const headers = {};
  headers[headerName] = headerValue;
  /*Instead of data object, you will create a formData*/
  const data = {
    /*Some data*/
  };
  Ember.$.ajax(
    {
      url: '/path-to-resource/id-of-resource',
      headers,
      type: "PUT",
      data
    }
  )
    .then(
      (payload) => {
        this.store.pushPayload(payload);
      },
      (response) => {
        this.set('errorMessage', stringifyError(response));
      }
    )
    .always(() => {
      this.set('isLoading', false);
    });
});
```

**UPD:** There is an addon, [ember-cli-form-data](https://github.com/funtusov/ember-cli-form-data) which claims to add support of file upload to ember data. I didn't try it myself, so can't say if it works and how good.

Comment: Yes, it sounds good. But I use `ember-simple-auth` and it adds `Authorization` header to request with access token. But when I use `jQuery` ajax I have problem to get access token from `ember-simple-auth`. Do you have some idea?

Comment: @Dmitro in example above I added header (`` this.get('session').authorize `` piece). This is method that ember-simple-auth docs recommends to use for ajax requests

Answer (score 1):

You can give it try using popular ember addon for this.
 [ember-plupload](https://github.com/tim-evans/ember-plupload) and [ember-uploader](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader) addon